# Wrong way to deploy Python Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, deployment

I've been trying to find out how to correctly deploy a Python app I've written using Flask. It does work, but all I ever see is how to deploy using FastCGI, uWSGI, or other similar, so that leads me to believe my method is wrong.

Basically I have a Flask app that has routes like `/api/1.0/news/` and when I run the app locally, I access it via eg. `http://localhost:5000/api/1.0/news/` and I get a the jsonified response that I expect.

Now, on my VPS that uses nginx, I have set it up in the same way and allowed port 5000 in `ufw`. So when on the server I run this:
`python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0` it runs it just like in my local environment. I can then access the same features using the real IP and the JSON response is exactly what is expected when I open `http://1.2.3.4:5000/api/1.0/news` with a browser.

Would it be wrong to keep it running like this in a `screen` on Ubuntu 14.04? Since from what I gather, the purpose of FastCGI, uWSGI, etc. is simply to translate the requests to something the app understands? Or do they also provide some other critical/important advantages over the above method?

The purpose for it is to be a non-public API that my public-facing frontend uses internally. It would not possible for 3rd parties to access the API. I will have authentication within the Python app later for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/), "Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and by default serves only one request at a time.", while other methods like FastCGI and uWSGI do that.

Comment: Ooh, that's quite critical. Somehow I overlooked that part, thanks!